# undefined on variable with async await es6 function

Tags: javascript, async-await, es6-promise

Not sure why I keep getting undefined on the possibleAnagrams variable, any help would be greatly appreciated!

```
const anagramica = require('anagramica');

const processBody = async (generatedString, arrayOfWords) => {
  const possibleAnagrams = await anagramica.all(generatedString, (err, response) => {
    if (err) {
      console.log(`Could not find possible anagrams : ${err}`);
    }
    else {
      console.log("1", response.all);
      /// [ Array ] ///
      const array = response.all;
      console.log("2", array);
      /// [ Array ] ///
      return array;
    }
  })
  console.log("3", possibleAnagrams)
  /// undefined ///

  return { possibleAnagrams, arrayOfWords }
}
```

Comment: It doesn't look like `anagramica.all` is a Promise. It has a callback function. That means you don't need async/await necessarily, you can just access the response value in the callback

Comment: For `await` to work, `anagramica.all` would need to return a promise. Looking at their docs, it seems like they don't support this, only callbacks. You could easily change that by using a module like [`es6-promisify`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/es6-promisify)

Comment: @Nick just removed the async / await from the function and still get an undefined, even tried pushing the response array into a new Array and the value is still undefined

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like `anagramica` does not return a Promise. If you'd like to use async/await, consider turning it into a Promise.

```
const anagramica = require('anagramica');

const anagramicaPromise = generatedString => new Promise((res, rej) => {
  anagramica.all(generatedString, (err, response) => {
    if (err) {
      return rej(err);
    }
    res(response);
  }
});

const processBody = async (generatedString, arrayOfWords) => {
  try {
    const possibleAnagrams = await anagramicaPromise(generatedString);
    console.log("3", possibleAnagrams);
    return { possibleAnagrams, arrayOfWords }
  } catch(err) {
    console.log(`Could not find possible anagrams : ${err}`);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Same as @Nick, but using [`es6-promisify`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/es6-promisify) module:

```
const { promisify } = require('es6-promisify');
const anagramica = require('anagramica');

const processBody = async (generatedString, arrayOfWords) => {
  try {
    const { all: possibleAnagrams } = await promisify(anagramica.all)(generatedString);
    return { possibleAnagrams, arrayOfWords };
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(`Could not find possible anagrams : ${err}`);
  }
};
```